# Row counter for looping macro not updating

Tags: excel, vba

I've been working on a Macro in Excel that should go through every sheet in the workbook, count the number of rows in a given sheet, and then format those rows. The other day I was able to run it successfully, with the macro formatting the entire workbook, however the next time I attempted to run it, the value for the number of rows did not update, and it only formatted the rest of the sheets up to the number of rows in the first sheet (i.e. if the first sheet is 22 rows long, it will format every sheet, but only the first 22 rows of that sheet, leaving the rest unformatted). I have attempted trying some changes to the macro, but cannot figure out how to resolve the issue so that the row counter resets for each sheet it loops through. Any help in trying to get this macro working is appreciated.

The macro as I currently have it written is as follows:

```
    Sub Formatting()
'
' Formatting Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+F
'
Dim ws As Worksheet
         
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    With ws
             
    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("$A$1:$X$" & lr).Select
        With Selection.Font
            .Name = "Century"
            .Size = 12
            .Strikethrough = False
            .Superscript = False
            .Subscript = False
            .OutlineFont = False
            .Shadow = False
            .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
        End With
        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        Columns("G:G").Select
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 75
        With Selection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlContext
            .MergeCells = False
        End With
        Cells.Select
        Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
        Range("A1").Select
    
    End With

    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: if you use With then any object attached to it needs to be prefixed with `.`: `lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` and `.Range("$A$1:$X$" & lr).Select` and `.Columns("G:G").Select` and `.Range("A1").Select` and `.Cells.Select` and `.Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit`

Comment: You could also get rid of the selects and work `with` the other ranges, e.g., `With ws / With .Columns("G")`... better to get in the habit of not using `select`/`activate` whenever possible.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you for your comment. I made those changes and received an error for "Select method of Range class failed" for the line ".Range("$A$1:$X$" & lr).Select". Is there something else I might additionally be missing?

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of making your `formatting` subroutine more specific, I have pulled out the formatting itself to `private` subroutines, so you can see what you're working with.  You format a designated range and its font, then separately format column G; both of which add bulk to your base functions and are repeated.

Beyond that, I have removed the `Select` items, aside from the "A1" select to reset position on each sheet.

Imparting my comments on your code (untested):

```
Sub Formatting()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        With ws     
            Dim lr as Long:  lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            DesignatedRangeFormatting .Range("$A$1:$X$" & lr)
            ColumnGFormatting .Columns("G")
            .Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit
            .Select
            .Range("A1").Select
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub

Private Sub DesignatedRangeFormatting(rng as Range)
    With rng.Font
        .Name = "Century"
        .Size = 12
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontNone
    End With
    With rng
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ColumnGFormatting(rng as Range)
    With rng
        .ColumnWidth = 75
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Edit1:  Added `.Select` before `.Range("A1").Select` to ensure the current sheet is selected, which resolves the RTE1004.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and for taking the time to type out and demonstrate the change to the structure. I attempted to test the code and received an error for "Select method of Range class failed" error for this solution also, so I am missing something elsewhere, though I'm not experienced enough to be sure how to resolve this issue

Comment: @Leigh on which line?

Comment: Apologies, I received it on the ".Range("A1").Select" line in the first section

Comment: @Leigh comment out the line and run it.  I'm not sure why you're getting RTE1004 on that line, where it's equivalent to `.Cells(1,1).Select`, but it shouldn't affect the overarching functionality of formatting.  If that runs when commented out, then try changing the line to `.Cells(1,1).Select` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: with that line removed it ran but made no changes to the formatting, and with the equivalent line it threw the same error

Comment: @Leigh I just tested/ran the code I provided and it executed and changed formatting on each sheet, after commenting out the `.select` line.  if I add `.Select` to select the correct sheet before I select a cell, this works.  It is tied to only being able to select what is current (one of many issues with `Select` in general).

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance with this. I attempted to use the changes you provided, and I am not sure if I am missing a step along the way, but when I try and run it  I receive an error for "Method 'Select' of object '_Worksheet' failed" for the .Select line. Looking at some other postings, I did attempt to change the .Select to a .Activate, and that configuration ran without errors but made no changes to the workbook.